# Entity framework migrate.exe gives log in error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When I tried to update database from [migrate.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj618307.aspx).

> migrate xxx.dll /connectionStringName="MYDBString" 
>   /startupConfigurationFile="xxx.dll.config"

It shows below error

> ERROR: The user does not have permission to perform this action.

How to provide user credentials in command

Answer (score 1):

You can try as shown below.This is just an example.Please replace it with your actual values.

```
Migrate.exe MyDemo.dll /connectionString=”Data Source=localhost;Initial 
Catalog=MyDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=myid;Password=mypw” 
/connectionProviderName=”System.Data.SqlClient”
```

Comment: I got access to database. By that i was able to run command successfully. Sorry man didn't check yours as i didn't had sql server authentication credentials.